# call methods and objects using php

Tags: php, oop, callback

i have this code :

```
   <?PHP
 function call_and_set( $obj, $txt){
                         return call_user_method('example', $obj, $txt);
                    }

        class test{

                function example($text){
                        echo $text;
                    }

            }
            $test = new test();
       call_and_set($test, "Hello World!");
    ?>
```

in my code i don't always want to use

$test = new test ....

I want to use the name directly instead of `$test`. For example:

```
call_and_set("test", "Hellow World!").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a factory method pattern or something like that. With a factory method you can create a class based on a string. In PHP it's not that hard. Try something like this:

```
<?PHP

    function call_and_set( $className, $txt) {
         $obj = ProductFactory::create($className);
         return call_user_method('example', $obj, $txt);
    }

    class test
    {

        function example($text){
            echo $text;
        }

    }
            
    class ProductFactory
    {
        public static function create($className) {
            //Add some checks and/or include class files
            return new $className();
        } 
    }           
            
    call_and_set("test", "Hello World!");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but its a little unclear.  You can specify the name of the class you want to instantiate as a variable name:

```
<?php

class test {}

$test = 'test';

$testObj = new $test;
```

It may be a good idea to verify that the class exists prior to attempting to instantiate it, however:

```
if(class_exists($test)) {
    $testObj = new $test;
}
```